# Mongodb find best match

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, recommendation-engine

I would like to build a query that returns the best matching document in the DB.

i.e I would like to find a document with the following fields - 
"animal":"dog"
"color":"brown"
"pattern":"dots"
"size":"small"

If there is no document that has all the above fiels and their corresponding values I would like the query to return the best match. f.e {"animal":"dog", "color":"brown", "size":"small"}

Can I implement a recursive query in mongo db? If so, how?
Should I use mapReduce, if so, how?
One can think of this problem more as a recommendation system problem in the way I would like to recommend on the item(document) that fits best to the given values, I would appreciate if someone knows a good way to implement the above

I'm using mongodb mongoose and nodejs.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a thought -- you might be able to use the aggregation framework to match on the fields, and keep a count (score) for the number of matches, then sort on that (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/). (And, no you can't do a 'recursive query' natively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the performance implications of a recursive query but something like this should work. It removes the last property from the query and tries again if no match is found:

```
var AnimalSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    atype: { type: String },
    color: {type:String},
    pattern: {type:String},
    size : {type:String}
});

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal',AnimalSchema);

//test data
//var dalmation = new Animal({
//    atype:'dog',
//    color: 'black and white',
//    pattern: 'spots',
//    size: 'big'
//});

//dalmation.save(function(err){
//    var yorkie = new Animal({
//        atype:'dog',
//        color:'brown',
//        pattern:'mixed',
//        size:'small'
//    });
//    yorkie.save(function(yer){
//         bestMatch({'atype':'dog','size':'big','color':'brown'},function(err,animal){
//             console.log(err,animal);
//         })
//    });
//});

function bestMatch(params,cb){
    Animal.findOne(params,function(err,animal){
        if (err || !animal){
           var keys = Object.keys(params);
           if (keys.length){
               delete params[keys.pop()];
               bestMatch(params,cb);
           }else{
               cb('No matches',null);
           }
        }else{
            cb(null,animal);
        }
    });
}

bestMatch({'atype':'dog','size':'big','color':'brown'},function(err,animal){
    console.log(err,animal);
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to see an answer using the aggregation framework. It would be great to see one!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you appear to only be searching text fields, one possibility is to use the new (and currently "experimental") [text search feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/) in MongoDB 2.4.  This allows you to create a full text index on one or more fields, including [field weighting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) for relevance.

For example:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex(
    // Fields to index
    {
        animal:  "text",
        color:   "text",
        pattern: "text",
        size:    "text"
    },

    // Options
    {
        name: "best_match_index",

        // Adjust field weights (default is 1)
        weights: {
            animal: 5,  // Most relevant search field
            size:   4   // Also relevant
       }
    }
)
```

[Results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search/#text-search-output) will be returned in order of relevance with scoring based on the associated field weights.

Note that search keywords are also [stemmed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), so this   may have some unexpected results if you are expecting exact matches.  You can put your terms in double quotes to take advantage of [phrase matching](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/search-for-text/#match-phrases) for more specific matches.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested but I get a "too many indexes" error

Comment: @Liatz: How many indexes do you have (`db.collection.getIndexes().length`)?  This error suggests you either have too many indexes on the collection or have tried to create multiple text indexes (2.4 only allows one text index per collection).

Comment: Which version supports multiple indexes?  (I need to use 4-5 indexes and wights in the same collection)

Comment: You can have multiple regular indexes, but full text indexes are currently limited to one per collection in MongoDB 2.4 (where the feature is still considered "beta").  What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @Liatz: the text search feature is only available with MongoDB 2.4, and is currently limited to a single *text* index (but you can have multiple non-text indexes).  The example as written will work with different weights for each field which could satisfy the relevance you are after.  If you are getting a "too many indexes" error this suggests you either have tried to create multiple text search indexes or have reached the per-collection limit of 64 indexes (which seems unlikely).  If you are trying to create 4-5 *text* indexes on the same collection, this is not supported yet.

Comment: I don't understand how the example as writter above suppose to work as there are more than one text index (4 to be exact) :        animal:  "text",
color:   "text",
pattern: "text",
size:    "text"

Comment: @Liatz: Those are four `text` *fields* that are part of a single index definition.  There's only one [ensureIndex()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/) call.  The [`weights`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/) specified in the options section of the index allow you to set which fields are more relevant in the match score.  Results are ordered by the match score, so a document matching values for all fields would appear before a document matching only one field.